# Remove border around WP text widgets

Tags: css, wordpress, widget

I would like to remove the border around the widgets on my home page. The CSS of my theme removes this universally. I thought I could specify the location and name of the Div text widget, (ie text-7, text-6) etc. and alter this. I can control the elements within the widget doing this, but it still will not remove the border. For example, the text widget:

```
#text-7. {border:1px solid transparent; text align: center}
```

Centers the elements, but does not remove the border. I've tried a few variations with no luck. Here is the source code: http://pastebin.com/7dSUebhk. Link to the live site in the comments below.

Thank you very much.

Alex

Comment: Here is the live site: http://mefo1.ecin1prod1lnx1.com/

Comment: @Chris Thank you! Sadly still no luck. I also tried being more specific to isolate that widget ( #sidebar #text-7.widget ) with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no border around the `div#text-7` element on your page so that is why your css does not remove the border. There is a border around `div.sidebox` which if you add:

```
.sidebox {border:0px}
```

Will remove all sidebox borders.

Your options are: a) use javascript/jquery to select the parent div of `#text-7` and remove the border that way, b) add a unique ID to the .sidebox DIVs so you can then remove the border for the specific sidebox DIV.